# How to split list of filenames into groups of n items to perform some command on each group in command line?

Tags: bash

I have a folders of files that belong together in groups of variable number, named in order of time they were created. In a folder, if it's groups of three in this case, then the first three videos belong together, and the 4th-6th videos together etc. How can I use command line to perform a command on these groups of three filenames?

To be more specific if it matters at all,I'd actually like to merge every group of n files using mkvmerge using a command like:

`$ mkvmerge -o newfile.mkv '[' file1.mkv ... filen.mkv ']'`

Edit:

In these example directories, pre/ has four videos that I'd say want to group into twos. the first two go together, the last two go together.
Next, in post/ the first three go together, the last three go together. I.e. the groups follow the order that they were named always.

- pre/
  ---2017-01-03-10-23.mkv
  ---2017-01-03-10-28.mkv
  ---2017-01-03-11-04.mkv
  ---2017-01-03-11-10.mkv
- post/
  ---2017-01-03-08-01.mkv
  ---2017-01-03-08-10.mkv
  ---2017-01-03-08-23.mkv
  ---2017-01-03-08-59.mkv
  ---2017-01-03-09-08.mkv
  ---2017-01-03-09-15.mkv

Comment: Can you add an example directory with files? Are the files in a group always lexical neighbours, i.e., the alphabetically first *x* go together, then the alphabetically next *x* and so on?

Comment: yes exactly, see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take 3 files at a time and use them as argument for `mkvmerge`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mkv" | xargs -L 3 -I '{}' mkvmerge '[' {} {} {} ']'
```

Comment: so in the case where I have 2 files at a time or 4 files at a time, I would indicate that number after -L, and change the number of '{ }' between the square brackets?

Comment: You also could just use `... | xargs -n 3 mkvmerge`. See also the *bug* section of [xargs' man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html): *The -L option is incompatible with the -I option [...]*

Comment: Also don't forget the `sort` in between `find` and `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform certain operation on chunks (of constant size) of files, then perhaps the utility `parallel` could be of interest:

```
find ./post -type f -name "*.mkv" | sort | parallel -P1 -n3 mkvmerge '[' {1} {2} {3} ']'
```

Here, the `find` command first identifies the files of interest the names of which are consequently sorted. The command `parallel` then processes these files in chunks of size 3 (`-n3`). Moreover, with the `-P` option, you can control how many threads do the processing...